# How do I get rid of the KeyError I get when I click scissor for a rock, paper, scissor game in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

my code is running fine and all except for the time I click on scissors; rock and paper work fine without errors but I get a KeyError every time scissors is clicked.
I'd appreciate some help given.

I'm making a rock, paper, scissor game if you haven't understood so far lol.

Actually though, my rock and paper work fine but I'm not sure why scissor gives me an error. I copy-pasted the code block for rock and paper yet scissor doesn't work. Honestly, I'm confused.

I think my dictionary went wrong but not sure. Please help.

```
import random
from tkinter import *

outcomes = {
    "rock":{"rock":1,"paper":0,"scissors":2},
    "paper":{"rock":2,"paper":1,"scissors":0},
    "scissors":{"rock":0,"paper":2,"scissors":1}
}
comp_score = 0
player_score = 0


#Functions
def converted_outcome(number):
    if number == 1:
        return "rock"
    elif number == 2:
        return "paper"
    elif number == 3:
        return "scissors"


def outcome_handler(user_choice):
    global comp_score
    global player_score
    random_number = random.randint(1,3)
    computer_choice =  converted_outcome(random_number)
    outcome         =  outcomes[user_choice][computer_choice]
    
    player_choice_label.config(fg="red",text="Player Choice : "+str(user_choice))
    comp_choice_label.config(fg="green",text="Computer Choice : "+str(computer_choice))
    
    if outcome      == 2:
        player_score = player_score + 2
        player_score_label.config(text="Player : "+str(player_score))
        outcome_label.config(fg="blue",text="Outcome : Player Won")
    elif outcome    == 0:
        comp_score   = comp_score   + 2
        comp_score_label.config(text="Computer : "+str(comp_score))
        outcome_label.config(fg="blue",text="Outcome : Computer Won")
    elif outcome    == 1:
        player_score = player_score + 1
        comp_score   = comp_score   + 1
        player_score_label.config(text="Player : "+str(player_score))
        comp_score_label.config(text="Computer : "+str(comp_score))
        outcome_label.config(fg="blue",text="Outcome : Draw")
#Main Screen
master = Tk()
master.title("Rock, Paper, Scissors")

#Labels
Label(master, text="Rock, Paper, Scissors",font=("American Typewriter", 14)).grid(row=0,sticky=N,pady=10,padx=200)
Label(master, text="Please select an option",font=("American Typewriter", 12)).grid(row=1,sticky=N)
player_score_label = Label(master, text="Player: 0",font=("American Typewriter", 12))
player_score_label.grid(row=2,sticky=W)

comp_score_label = Label(master, text="Computer: 0",font=("American Typewriter", 12))
comp_score_label.grid(row=2,sticky=E)

player_choice_label = Label(master, font=("American Typewriter", 12))
player_choice_label.grid(row=3, sticky=W)

comp_choice_label = Label(master, font=("American Typewriter", 12))
comp_choice_label.grid(row=3, sticky=E)

outcome_label = Label(master, font=("Calibri",12))
outcome_label.grid(row=3, stick=N)

#Buttons 
Button(master, text="Rock", width=15,command=lambda:outcome_handler("rock")).grid(row=4,sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
Button(master, text="Paper", width=15,command=lambda:outcome_handler("paper")).grid(row=4,sticky=N, pady=5)
Button(master, text="Scissor", width=15,command=lambda:outcome_handler("scissor")).grid(row=4,sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)

#Dummy Label
Label(master).grid(row=5)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: `outcome_handler("scissor")`, the key is `scissors`

Comment: `outcome_handler("scissor"))` You have a typo (should be `scissors`)

Comment: Alright, thanks. It was a mistake on my end which I was dumb enough to ignore. Thanks. Appreciate the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

outcome_handler("scissor") this should be scissors

Comment: Sounds good. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

You have written `...lambda:outcome_handler("scissor")...`

It should be `...lambda:outcome_handler("scissors")...`

Comment: Alright, thanks!